# Display Sub-categories or Child Pages of Parent Cat/Page?

Tags: categories

I am seeking two codes which I haven't been able to find which would allow a child menu to be created in a sidebar.

A code to display the sub-categories of the parent category.

A code to display the sub-pages of the current page.

I remember having a theme that had these codes implemented which also allowed styling to be applied to current categories.  Maybe it has since been depreceated and maybe not - but I would sure appreciate if anybody had more information on these codes.

Answer (score 1):

for sub-pages of current page 
check [wp_list_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

```
<?php 
  $page_id = get_the_ID();
  wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of'=>$page_id ) );
?>
```

---

and for sub-categories of the parent category check [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php 
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
if( !empty($cat_id) ) {
  wp_list_categories( array( 'child_of'=> $cat_id ) );
}
?>
```